# Repository and Service layer, QueryDSL and Spring Data

Tags: spring, architecture, spring-data, software-design

I am using Spring Data and QueryDSL and I'm facing a situation where I have to retrieve a set of items based in one or more conditions. My question is:

Should I expect the service layer to provide my repositories with a predicate?

```
// Repository method
public void findFilteredItems(Predicate conditions);
```

Or should I isolate QueryDSL stuff within the repostory itself like this?

```
// Repository method
public void findFilteredItems(List<ItemFilter> conditions);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the cleanest way is the `List<ItemFilter>` approach, otherwise there is a tight coupling between the dependencies of the service layer and the data layer. Furthermore, you'd put a technology specific dependency in your repository interface definition.

But I would say it depends on your application. If you're dealing with a small application (or a microservice) where the repository layer won't be shared with any other project ever, there is nothing wrong with putting the `Predicate` in your repository's method signature.

I don't know how you create your `Predicate` objects. If you already have a converter which transforms `ItemFilter`s to `Predicates`, you could easily put that code in the repository and make the `ItemFilter` part of the repository interface.

Comment: Wouldn't this require one to provide a custom implementation for all repositories?